# Mongoose populate schema from different Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example i have SchemaA and SchemaB which both belong to different database. Inside SchemaA i have `doc.b = {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SchemaB'}`. When i am doing populate of this i got below error. `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "SchemaB". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)` From my research i have read that mongoose support population cross databases.
I am requiring mongoose multiple times for each schema, is that the problem?
Basically what i need is two different schema which is connecting to different databases to work together with populate. If i register schema on connection created by mongoose they will not be registered on the same list. If there a way to success that?

Comment: I found this [example](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3639#issuecomment-161785989) in Mongoose's github page. It shows you how to populate the model in one database from the data in another database.

Comment: This exmaple is working.

Comment: I have all my schemas in different files, connecting like in example, but throwing this error.

Comment: Don't forget to export and require your schemas, and attach them to your models before use.

Comment: Also, you should have only ONE instance of mongoose.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen yes, trying to rebuild some code to have one instance.

Comment: What i see in the example is `.populate('created_by', 'name email', User)`, he is passing User schema inside populate, how can i do that when i have object populate like `.populate({path: 'created_by',select: 'name email'})`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110769/discussion-between-blaze-sahlzen-and-gonchar-denys).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what we need to do is pass schema to population, something like this:

```
User.findOne({
    _id: req.user._id
}).populate({
    path: 'roomsContainer',
    model: RoomsContainer,
    populate: [{
        path: 'creator'
    },{
        path: 'users'
    },{
        path: 'rooms',
        model: Room
    }]
}).exec(function(err, user) {
    // do some magic
});
```

Where `User` belong to database one and `Room`, `RoomsContainer` belong to database two.

Answer (score 2):

```
const db1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27000/db1');
const db2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27001/db2');

const conversationSchema = new Schema({ numMessages: Number });
const Conversation = db2.model('Conversation', conversationSchema);

const eventSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  conversation: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: Conversation // `ref` is a **Model class**, not a string
  }
});
const Event = db1.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

Refrence [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents)

Comment: Great answer! I am actually using multiple microservices having their own databases within a docker-compose and this way worked for me. Thank you.